# In a PID without unit an ideal is maximal iff it is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, rngs

As the titles says, I need to show that in a PID $R$ an ideal is maximal iff it is prime. This is easy to do if $R$ has a multiplicative identity. I can not do it if $R$ does not have an identity. It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: A PID is an integral domain, which has a multiplicative identity.

Comment: @AlanSimonin I checked my book's definition. It doesn't include this.I checked my book's definition. It doesn't include this.

Comment: Quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) : "It is usually assumed that commutative rings and integral domains have a multiplicative identity even though this is not always included in the definition of a ring"

Comment: @AlanSimonin Does the theorem hold if one does not include an identity

Comment: I don't think that a prime ideal or a maximal ideal are well-defined if the ring has no multiplicative identity. In both cases, we demand the ideal not to contain the multiplicative identity of the ring (they must be proper ideals)

Comment: I don't see a problem in defining prime ideals in rings which do not have identity

Comment: No, that's not the point. A proper ideal must not containt the multiplicative identity of the ring, therefore the ring must have a multiplicative identity to do this test.

Comment: Why should we do the test ? Ii mean thats not the only way to ensure that an ideal is proper

Comment: @AlanSimonin Prime, maximal ideals, and proper ideals are perfectly well-defined for rings without unit, with no changes to the definition. Of course, we do lose some things we take for granted in rings with unit (like the existence of maximal ideals.)

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you for this information, honestly, I was stuck

Comment: @zaltan Where did you find this question, I am curious?

Comment: Is your ring commutative, of your definition of PID is "every *two-sided* ideal is principal"?

Comment: It's an interesting question, even for commutative rings. Is it right to assume that you meant to ask "a _non-zero_ ideal is maximal iff it is prime"? Since $(0)\subset\mathbb{Z}$ seems a prime ideal to me, while it most certainly isn't maximal.

Comment: @rschwieb I found it in Algebra by Hungerford

Comment: @ Matemáticos Chibchas Yes it is commutative.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with properties of PIDs when they don't have a unit. Is it still true that the prime ideals are the ones generated by prime elements? Are the prime elements exactly the irreducibles? Is it still a UFD? If these are still true, then the standard proof should still work here.

Comment: @zaltan It's really unlikely Hungerford intended to ask about a domain without a unit. For instance, you can see that he assumes integral domains have a unit in the proof to theorem 3.4. If he did not intend for there to be units, he would have a really hard time defining irreducible elements and handling UFD's to begin with. Finally, most authors don't put unnecessarily complicated problems as problem #1 in a section.

Comment: OK. Thanks everyone

Comment: @rschwieb, can you post this as an answer to remove from unanswered queue?

Comment: @RobertCardona No problem: done. At the time I did not know if someone would leap to the front and actually provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a CW answer intended to help clear this question from the unanswered queue.*

---

It's really unlikely Hungerford intended to ask about a domain without a unit. For instance, you can see that he assumes integral domains have a unit in the proof to theorem 3.4. If he did not intend for there to be units, he would have a really hard time defining irreducible elements and handling UFD's to begin with. Finally, most authors don't put unnecessarily complicated problems as problem #1 in a section.